# Using gluLookAt() causes the objects to spin

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I am making a game using OpenGL with Pygame. So far I was able to make cubes appear and make a cross hair. When I tried to implement looking around, things got... weird. I would run it and without even moving my mouse it would start spinning the screen everywhere when I used the `gluLookAt()` function. When I took that out, it worked but I couldn't look around. I was doing some testing and I even put in set data values to the function just to make sure that they were not changing and it still spun. Thanks in advance for whatever you are able to help me with and here is my code: [My code on GitHub](https://github.com/hippolippo/Game)

Comment: Can someone please help me with this? I have tried everything that I know.

Comment: Delete the `glLookAt` and do something like `modelview = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)` `glLoadIdentity()` `glRotate(-change[1]*0.1, 1, 0, 0)` `glRotate(change[0]*0.1, 0, 1, 0)` `glMultMatrixf(modelview)` instead

Comment: @Rabbid76 can you post an answer that  explains this a little more?

Comment: It's 23:51 at my place and I've to work tomorrow. I don't think it will completely satisfy you, but it's a step to the right direction. For now it's not enough for an answer. Possibly i'll make it to an answer tomorrow. The idea is `rotateY * rotateX * currentView`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ok thanks

Comment: @Rabbid76 can you answer it soon please?

Comment: @Rabbid76 When I tried to do what you said, it only made the cubes show up when they were on the edge of the screen and they were just triangles, they would seem to get really small and disappear if i tried to look straight at them. Here is a video of what I am experiencing: [video](https://youtu.be/FiA-DvtBlPc)

Comment: I find that when using gluLookAt or even with Rabbid76 solution of two rotates and the view model matrix that using glCullFace(GL_BACK) makes objects appear as they spin, either remove it or use glCullFace(GL_FRONT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there are 2 issues.

1. [`gluLookAt`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) sets up a view matrix. But this is not all. 
   `gluLookAt` multiplies the view matrix to the current matrix on the matrix stack, which is chosen by [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml).
   So your code concatenates the new view matrix to the existing view matrix. This causes that the objects start to spin rapidly.

Set the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) before you call `gluLookAt` to solve this issue. This causes that the model view matrix is set from scratch, independent on its former state.

```py
glLoadIdentity()
gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, facing[0], facing[1], lookingZ, 0, 1, 0)
```

2. This won't solve you issue completely, because at the point when you set the view matrix, then current matrix on the model view matrix  stack is the concatenation of the projection matirx and the view matrix. This cause the `glLoadIdentity` also skips the projection matrix.
   This behaviour can be solved with ease. Put the view matrix on the model view matrix stack (`GL_MODELVIEW`) and the projection matrix to the projection matrix stack (`GL_PROJECTION`):

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (width/height), 0.1, 100.0)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPushMatrix()
```

[image]

An much better and completely working solution is to apply a rotation matrix around the x and y axis to the view matrix. First apply the rotation matrix around the y axis (up vector) then the current view matrix and finally the rotation on the x axis:

```
view-matrix = rotate-X * view-matrix * rotate-Y
```

For this the current view matrix has to be read by [`glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGet.xml):

```py
modelview = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
glLoadIdentity()
glRotate(-change[1]*0.1, 1, 0, 0)
glMultMatrixf(modelview)
glRotate(change[0]*0.1, 0, 1, 0)
```

Note, this has to be done instead of:

<s>`glLoadIdentity()`</s>
<s>`gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, facing[0], facing[1], lookingZ, 0, 1, 0)`</s>

[image]

Complete `main` function ([renderingEngine.py](https://github.com/hippolippo/Game/blob/master/renderingEngine.py)), with the suggested changes:

```py
def main(world,x,y,z,width,height,renderDistance):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((width,height), DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glClearDepth(1.0)
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
    glCullFace(GL_BACK)
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    glDepthRange(0.0, 1.0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(45, (width/height), 0.1, 100.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glPushMatrix()

    #pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    facing = [0, 0, False]
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
                    pygame.quit()
                    return # TODO: Add pause
        newMousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        change = (newMousePos[0]-(width/2), newMousePos[1]-(height/2))
        pygame.mouse.set_pos([width / 2, height / 2])
        if facing[2]:
            facing[0] -= change[0]
        else:
            facing[0] += change[0]
        facing[1] += change[1]
        while facing[0] > width:
            facing[0] = 2*width-facing[0]
            facing[2] = not facing[2]
        while facing[0] < 0:
            facing[0] = 0-facing[0]
            facing[2] = not facing[2]
        if facing[1] < 0:
            facing[1] = 0
        if facing[1] > height:
            facing[1] = height
        radius = (width**2+height**2)**.5+1
        lookingZ = (-1*facing[0]**2-facing[1]**2+radius**2)**.5
        if facing[2]:
            lookingZ *= -1

        #print(lookingZ, facing[0], facing[1], radius)
        print(facing[0], facing[1], lookingZ)

        #glLoadIdentity()
        #gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, facing[0], facing[1], lookingZ, 0, 1, 0)

        modelview = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glRotate(-change[1]*0.1, 1, 0, 0)
        glMultMatrixf(modelview)
        glRotate(change[0]*0.1, 0, 1, 0)

        xmin = round(x-renderDistance[0])
        ymin = round(y-renderDistance[1])
        zmin = round(z-renderDistance[2])
        if xmin < 0:
            xmin = 0
        if ymin < 0:
            ymin = 0
        if zmin < 0:
            zmin = 0
        xmax = round(x+renderDistance[0])
        ymax = round(y+renderDistance[1])
        zmax = round(z+renderDistance[2])
        dims = world.dims()
        if xmax > dims[0]:
            xmax = dims[0]
        if ymax > dims[1]:
            ymax = dims[1]
        if zmax > dims[2]:
            zmax = dims[2]
        selection = world.select_data(xrange = (xmin, xmax), yrange = (ymin, ymax), zrange = (zmin, zmax))
        blocks = selection.iterate(ignore=(None,))
        glClearDepth(1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        for bl in blocks:
            locations = bl[0]
            block = bl[1]
            cube(locations[0] - x, locations[1] - y, locations[2] - z, block)
            #print(locations[0],locations[1],locations[2])

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()
        glOrtho(0.0, width, 0.0, height, -1.0, 1.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        crosshair(width/2, height/2, 20)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glPopMatrix()
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glPopMatrix()

        glCullFace(GL_BACK)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(.01)
```